# How to create a page in locomotive cms without any parent page i.e. no parent

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, locomotivecms

I am using [locomotivecms](https://github.com/locomotivecms/engine) and in locomotive, I have an `index` with child pages `about-us` and `contact-us`.

I need to create other pages without parents, but the page URLs are coming out like:

```
my_host_url/sitename/index
my_host_url/sitename/index/about-us
my_host_url/sitename/index/contact-us
```

What I would like is to create a page structure like this:

```
my_host_url/sitename/live
```

i.e. without parent.

Answer (score 0):

[image]if you are using wagon with locomotive you can use following command to generate pages

```
bundle exec wagon generate page live
```

or else you can simply create a page in app/views/pages/live.liquid and update the content accordingly

Comment: Shani thanks for your response, I have created a new page like the above command only, but if you see into the settings of Home(index) page their is no option for parent but for other pages there is always a parent option. I need a page without any parent same as index.

Comment: not sure why you cant access page like my_host_url/sitename/live with above. As far as I know in Locomotive cms,  all pages are part of an inherticance tree. The parent of any page under app/views/pages is app/views/pages/index.liquid. 

Have you check the slug of the live page ?

Comment: ---
title: Live
published: true
slug: live
---

Comment: Shani, could you please help me to resolve one more thing..how can I remove slug name from page like...if I have url "my_host_url/parent/page" but need to be like "my_host_url/page".

Comment: Hi 
I have a image attached. Logged into admin just created a page called live and it is slug is live and I can clearly access it http://localhost:3000/live.
Hope that helps or may be I am missing something you do differently.